# Inserting Data at the certain positon of a column in a table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to insert data at the start on a column? Lets say like this.

[image]

What i mean is,is it possible to insert a bunch of data from 1 column of a table into another table starting at the row position?

tysm

Comment: What you mean by row position, it doesn't matter with how u insert data, its always how u order the data which matters

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, you cannot do exactly what you want.  You can put the data side-by-side using variables and aggregation:

```
select max(col1) as col1, max(col2) as col2
from ((select (@rn1 := @rn1 + 1) as rn, col1, NULL as col2
       from table1 t1 cross join (select @rn1 := 0) params
       order by ??
      ) union all
      (select (@rn2 := @rn2 + 1) as rn, NULL, col1
       from table2 t2 cross join (select @rn2 := 0) params
       order by ??
      )
     ) tt
group by rn;
```

The `order by ??` is for the column that specifies the ordering.  If you don't care about the ordering, then just remove the `order by`.  The ordering within the two columns will be arbitrary.